# Libvirt: Change network interface of running domain

Tags: python, libvirt

The Virt-Manager is capable of modifying network interfaces of running domains, for example changing the connected network.

I want to script this in python with the libvirt-API.

```
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')
deb = conn.lookupByName('Testdebian')
xml = deb.XMLDesc()
xml = replace('old-network-name', 'new-network-name')
deb.undefine()
deb = conn.defineXML(xml)
```

But that doesn't work. The network isn't changed. Can someone give me a tipp how to modify a running domain with libvirt? I couldn't find anything about that in the docs. But it must be possible as the Virt-Manager can do it.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I managed to perform the network change via virsh:

```
virsh update-device 16 Testdebian.xml
```

Testdebian.xml must contain the interface device only, not the whole domain-XML.

But how can I do this via the libvirt-API? There seems to be no method to perform update-device through the API....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

```
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')
deb = conn.lookupByName('Testdebian')

deb.updateDeviceFlags(xml)
```

where xml is a string containing the device description.

I found this in the [Libvirt's JavaDocs](https://libvirt.org/sources/java/javadoc/org/libvirt/Domain.html#libvirt), the Python and C documentation seem to lack a lot of features.

Answer (score 2):

```
updateDeviceFlags(xml, flags=0) method of libvirt.virDomain instance
Change a virtual device on a domain, using the flags parameter
to control how the device is changed.  VIR_DOMAIN_AFFECT_CURRENT
specifies that the device change is made based on current domain
state.  VIR_DOMAIN_AFFECT_LIVE specifies that the device shall be
changed on the active domain instance only and is not added to the
persisted domain configuration. VIR_DOMAIN_AFFECT_CONFIG
specifies that the device shall be changed on the persisted domain
configuration only.  Note that the target hypervisor must return an
error if unable to satisfy flags.  E.g. the hypervisor driver will
return failure if LIVE is specified but it only supports modifying the
persisted device allocation.

This method is used for actions such changing CDROM/Floppy device
media, altering the graphics configuration such as password,
reconfiguring the NIC device backend connectivity, etc.
```

Where VIR_DOMAIN* are constants definded in libvirt module.

The bad thing is that you can't modify mac or pci address this way. Eg

```
libvirtError: operation failed: no device matching mac address 68:80:82:e3:7b:4b found on 0000:00:09.0
```

Comment: Another bad thing is, that interfaces configured with "network" type are presented as "bridge" type, when domain is active, so you can't use portgroups alter configuragion of a running domain.